# Why is the copy constructor not called in this case - Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an object called `Myobj` and this object has all the defaults (copy cstr , move cstr, assignment and cpy assignment). Now suppose there is a method as such

```
void fooA(foo& f){..}  --->A
```

and then another method as such

```
void fooB(foo f){..}   --->B
```

Now when asked why the copy constructor is not called in case of A and is called in-case of B my answer and understanding is as follows. Kindly correct me if its wrong

The reason its not called for case A is because `foo&` is a reference to foo and not `foo`
therefore the copy constructor of `foo` is not called. The `f` in `case A`  is simply an alias to the passed object.

The reason its called in case B is because `foo` is the object foo and not a reference to the foo.Therefore the copy constructor of `foo` is called. The cpy cnstr is `foo::foo(const foo& f)`. So incase of the statement

```
fooB(someobject);
```

The equivalent would be on the function as

```
void fooB(foo f){..} gives  fooB f (someobject); //Cpy constr is called
```

Kindly let me know if my answer and understanding is correct

Comment: Yeah fixed it. Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but IMO you are wording is quite strange or maybe you are over-complicating things a bit.

The second signature uses a "pass by value" method. As opposed to the first example, where a "pass by reference" is used. The idea is that you operate on the value of the argument, and not the argument itself.

This means a temporary copy of the passed parameter is made, with the lifetime limited by the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct.  I think you mean in the first case that it is a reference to `f` not a reference to `foo`.  Same with in the second case it is that you're passing a copy to `f` not the `f` itself.

Comment: The first case is a reference to foo. The second case is not a reference. The types are different

Comment: No theyre the same types.  The first is passing an argument by reference, the second is passing by value.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: In both cases, the function that is called is getting a `foo`

Comment: `foo&` is not the same as `foo`.  There are times when a static cast (for example) will not work if you forget a `&`.  Of course in both cases there is a `foo` (same type) involved.